# Why Zeros are appeneded to actual message while calculating CRC?

Tags: crc

I was studying CRC algorithms and was refering to "[A PAINLESS GUIDE TO CRC ERROR DETECTION ALGORITHMS](http://www.zlib.net/crc_v3.txt)" and "[CRC Implementation Code in C](http://www.barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/CRC-Calculation-C-Code)"

Both pages mention that, say we need a 8bit CRC, 8 zeros are appended to message before starting calculations. Why this is done so?

Answer (score 0):

So that the CRC can replace those zeros, effectively appending the CRC to the message, resulting in a message+CRC with a total CRC of zero.